# selenium python: driver has no find_element_by attribute

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am very new in Selenium.

I want to find an element but driver has no **find_element_by** attribute (screenshot).
Any idea how can i fix the problem?

[image]

and I have created a TestBase class and defined my driver in this class:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize the driver object, so currently your `self.driver` is still not an instance of a `webdriver`.
So, you need to add something like

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("driver path")
```

where `driver path` is the path where you have installed the `chromedriver.exe` on your machine.
**UPD**:
After the question update.
It still means that `self.driver` is not recognized as an instance of `webdriver` there.
The `OverviewPage` class should contain / import the class / module where the driver is initialized i.e. the `TestBase` class

Comment: I have created a TestBase class and defined my driver in this class. (I have edited my question). maybe you can help how to call driver in my second class, or how is it a better way to do? - Thanks